# Sublime Merge - keyboard shortcut for "File History"

Tags: sublimemerge

How can I make a keyboard shortcut for `Navigate > File History...` in Sublime Merge?

Answer (score 7):

The command for this is `file_history`; it will prompt you interactively in the command palette and commands of that nature need to be invoked via the `show_command_palette` command.

So, a key binding that duplicates what the menu item `Navigate > File History...` does would look like the following (using an example key; change that as desired):

```
    { 
      "keys": ["ctrl+alt+t"], 
      "command": "show_command_palette", "args": {"command": "file_history"}
    },
```

This binding goes into the `Default (<PLATFORM>).sublime-keymap` file in your Merge `User` package, where `<PLATFORM>` is one of `Linux`, `Windows` or `OSX` depending on what platform you're using.

You can locate the `User` package by choosing the `Preferences > Browse Packages` command from the menu and then navigating inside of the `User` package.

Note that just like Sublime, the `sublime-keymap` file is a JSON file that is a list of key bindings; thus if you don't already have key bindings, you need to wrap the key binding above in `[` and `]` characters to make it the first item in the list.